# How to insert records into a table using Sequel

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

This is my code to insert a few lines in my simple "series" table:

```
db = sequel.postgres(config['dbname'],:user=>config['user'],:password=>config['password'],:host=>config['host'],:port=>config['port'],:max_connections=>10)
@db.create_table? 'series' do
        primary_key "series_id" , :autoincrement=>true
        String "series_name"
    end
seriesDS = db['series']
seriesDS.insert('series_name' => 'test_value')
```

At `seriesDS.insert` I get a

```
Sequel::DatabaseError - PG::SyntaxError: ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « series »
```

I didn't manage to get the full SQL query for analysys in STDOUT. It's strange because I added this:

```
logger = Logger.new STDOUT
    logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
    db.loggers << logger
```

It appears to be generating the wrong SQL, but I have no clue to the error's source.

I'm using:

- Ruby 2.2.5
- Sequel 4.4.1
- Postgresql 9.6

The program is launched using `ruby -E utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

Sequel uses Ruby symbols to represent SQL identifiers.  At the very least, you must use `seriesDS = db[:series]`.

Other cases where you want an SQL identifier you should probably switch from using strings to symbols.

Comment: I'v discovered more ruby since this question, i understand that symbols are a better way to go. But why did the create table is working if symbols are a mandatory syntax ?